# Trying to load data from plist and refresh screen

Tags: ios, uiview, crash, plist

So here is my plist. All i want to do is refresh the screen when the button is pressed. I am getting no errors but it keeps crashing on me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>question</key>
    <string>2 + 2 = ?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>3</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>question</key>
    <string>2 + 4 = ?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>9</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

And here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]];

currentQuestion = -1;
[self showNextQuestion];
}
-(void) showNextQuestion{
    currentQuestion++;
    int numItems = [rootArray count];
    NSMutableArray *question = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems]; 

for (NSDictionary *itemData in rootArray) {
    [question addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"question"]];
    [A addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"A"]];
    [B addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"B"]];
    [C addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"C"]];

    self.questionasked.text =question[currentQuestion];
    self.answer1.text = A[currentQuestion];
    self.answer2.text = B[currentQuestion];
    self.answer3.text = C[currentQuestion];
    }
}

-(IBAction)nextQ:(UIButton *) sender{
[self showNextQuestion];

}
```

The button is declared as an action which simply loops around the viewcontroller when it is pressed

Comment: what do you get in your console-log when the crash happens?

Comment: 2013-02-22 16:43:38.726 fypdemo[14532:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<additionalmathViewController 0x748bb10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ScreenRep.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: okay, your problem relates to your xib file. Try checking all outlets of xib and make sure they are bound to properties in your class file.

Comment: Okay so I done what u said and it worked but the screen wont refresh to the next item in the plist!

Comment: So when i am trying to get the button to reload the viewcontroller again I just alt+clicked and drop it on the same viewcontroller...so its like a loop is that correct

Comment: Have you hooked up your UIButton touch down event to your event handler correctly? try writing NSLog(@"hit detected!"); in your -(IBAction)nextQ:(UIButton *) sender and check that is got fired in your log console

Answer (score 0):

I see at least one problem with your code:

```
 rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
 pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Gives you an auto released object, that are released when you leave the scope of `viewDidLoad`

Try making `rootArray` into a property

Comment: I already have declared it as a property in my .h
     `@property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *rootArray;`

Comment: it should not be weak, but strong. also try accessing it with self.rootArray. But this is not related to your crash. See comment above:)